# Problem NestJS/TypeORM : [Nest] 3100 ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ProjetslaboService (?)

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, exceptionhandler

After having followed the following tutorial in full:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JK5aynTxKjM&list=PL4bT56Uw3S4zIAOX1ddx8oJS6jaD43vZC

I decided to do my crud based on this:
I tested TypeORM with my category (Categorie), so just a simple table with no foreign key or anything and it worked like a charm and the program runs CRUD.
I said so I decided to make several tables including the "ProjectsLabo" table, with two foreign keys.

But problem when I incorporate in my module the three other modules I have an error:
[Nest] 3100 - 25/01/2023, 14:39:29 ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ProjetslaboService (?). Please make sure that the argument ProjetslaboDtoRepository at index [0] is available in the ProjetslaboMo
dule context.

Potential solutions:

- Is ProjetslaboModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ProjetslaboDtoRepository is a provider, is it part of the current ProjetslaboModule?
- If ProjetslaboDtoRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ProjetslaboModule?

```
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ProjetslaboDtoRepository */ ]
  })
```

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ProjetslaboService (?). Please make sure that the argument ProjetslaboDtoRepository at index [0] is available in the ProjetslaboModule context.

Potential solutions:

- Is ProjetslaboModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ProjetslaboDtoRepository is a provider, is it part of the current ProjetslaboModule?
- If ProjetslaboDtoRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ProjetslaboModule?

```
    @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ProjetslaboDtoRepository */ ]
    })
```

Here is an example of the LaboProjects module :

[image: folder]

projetslabo.dto.ts

```
    import { IsNotBlank } from "../../decorators/is-not-blank.decorator";
    export class ProjetslaboDto {
    //@IsString()
    //@IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNotBlank({message : 'Serveur : the name is not empty'})
    nom?: string;
    }
```

projetslabo.controller.ts

```
    @Controller('projetslabo')
    export class ProjetslaboController {
    constructor(private readonly projetslaboService: ProjetslaboService) {
    }
    
    @Get()
    async GetAll() {
    return await this.projetslaboService.getAll();
    }
    
    @Get(':id')
    async GetOne(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number) {
    return await this.projetslaboService.findById(id);
    }
    }
```

projetslabo.entity.ts

```
    @Entity({ name: 'projetslabo' })
    export class ProjetslaboEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    idProjetsLabo: number;
    
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 40, nullable: false })
    nom: string;
    
    @ManyToOne(() => ValeurslaboEntity, (ValeurslaboEntity) => ValeurslaboEntity.idValeursLabo , {nullable : false})
    FK_idValeursLabo: ValeurslaboEntity
    
    @ManyToOne(() => AnneeslaboEntity, (AnneeslaboEntity) => AnneeslaboEntity.idAnneesLabo, {nullable : false})
    FK_idAnneesLabo: AnneeslaboEntity
    }
```

Projetslabo.module.ts

```
    @Module({
      
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ProjetslaboEntity])],
    providers: [ProjetslaboService],
    controllers: [ProjetslaboController],
    })
    export class ProjetslaboModule {}
```

projetslabo.repository.ts

```
    @EntityRepository(ProjetslaboEntity)
    export class ProjetslaboRepository extends Repository<ProjetslaboEntity>{}
```

projetslabo.service.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ProjetslaboService {
    constructor(
    @InjectRepository(ProjetslaboDto)
    private projetslaboRepository: ProjetslaboRepository,){}
    async getAll(): Promise<ProjetslaboEntity[]> {
    const list = await this.projetslaboRepository.find();
    if (!list.length) {
    throw new NotFoundException(
    new MessageDto('Serveur : La liste est vide'),
    );
    }
    return list;
    }
    async findById(idProjetsLabo: number): Promise<ProjetslaboEntity> {
    const annees = await this.projetslaboRepository.findOneBy({
    idProjetsLabo,
    });
    if (!annees) {
    throw new NotFoundException(
    new MessageDto("Serveur : Cette année n'existe pas"),
    );
    }
    return annees;
    }
```

app.module.ts

```
    @Module({
    imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
    envFilePath: '.env',
    isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'mariadb',
    host: configService.get<string>(DB_HOST),
    port: +configService.get<number>(DB_PORT),
    username: configService.get<string>(DB_USER),
    password: configService.get<string>(DB_PASSWORD),
    database: configService.get<string>(DB_DATABASE),
    entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    }),
    inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    CategoriesModule,
    /*Problem with this 3 modules
    ProjetslaboModule,
    ValeurslaboModule,
    AnneeslaboModule,
    */
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Can you help me please?
Nestjs/core : 9.0.0
Nestjs/typeorm : 9.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `ProjetslaboDto` to your `@InjectRepository()` when you should be passing `ProjetslaboEntity` as that's what you've told `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` about.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjetslaboService {
  constructor(
-    @InjectRepository(ProjetslaboDto)
+    @InjectRepository(ProjetslaboEntity)
    private projetslaboRepository: ProjetslaboRepository,){}
...
```